# Tensorflow.Js IS MESSED UP

Tags: python, node.js, angular, typescript, tensorflow

for 4 days I am trying to use tensorflow.js and its Handpose model in Angular, but it doesn't work. I am installing them by

```
npm i @tensorflow/tfjs @tensorflow-models/handpose
```

It installs them, but when import them like this:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import * as handpose from '@tensorflow-models/handpose'
```

But it gives me BUNCH of errors, looks like this:

```
Error: node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/hash_util.d.ts:2:49 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

2 export declare function hexToLong(hex: string): Long;
                                                  ~~~~


Error: node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/hash_util.d.ts:3:69 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

3 export declare function fingerPrint64(s: Uint8Array, len?: number): Long;
                                                                      ~~~~


Error: node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/training.d.ts:144:22 - error TS2420: Class 'LayersModel' incorrectly implements interface 'InferenceModel'.
  Types of property 'inputs' are incompatible.
    Type 'SymbolicTensor[]' is not assignable to type 'ModelTensorInfo[]'.
      Type 'SymbolicTensor' is not assignable to type 'ModelTensorInfo'.
        Types of property 'shape' are incompatible.
          Type 'Shape' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
            Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
              Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

144 export declare class LayersModel extends Container implements tfc.InferenceModel {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/keras_format/topology_config.d.ts:17:5 - error TS2411: Property 'input_shape' of type 'Shape | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'PyJsonValue'.

17     input_shape?: Shape;
```

Tried also installing the latest version of typescript :

```
npm i typescript@latest
```

Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you get it worked out?

Comment: No, but they gave me a different solution. Link: https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-js-can-t-be-used/15400/7